# Update specific value in JSON data of String column type in DataBricks

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I'm having table in databricks catalog with column type String. It contains JSON, I wanted to update particular value from it for example "key1". I've converted it to json using `from_json` but unable to understand how to update the same.

> select from_json(tags,'STRUCT<Key1: STRING, `Key2`: STRING'>) from
> table  where id='abc';

I tried update query with following syntax but none of them worked-

> tags:['Key1'] = 'test1'

> tags:`Key1` = 'test1'

> tags:Key1 = 'test1'

Any input appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Azure databricks or AWS?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Thanks for the response, We're using AWS.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Even if you have idea for Azure databricks, sharing that info might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to update `struct` columns.

- Unpack `struct` columns
- Update specific column
- Repack old & new column values using `named_struct`

Below is simple `SQL`

```
SELECT    
   named_struct(
      'key1',
      'test1',
      'key2',
      FROM_JSON(
          tags,
          'tags:struct<key1:string, key2:string>'
      ).tags.key2
   )
FROM input
WHERE id = 'abc'
```